# Asp.net Core publish is not deploying properly using Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm trying to deploy my asp.net core 3.1 website using the following command:

`dotnet publish -r win-x64 --self-contained true -c Beta -o C:\aPublish\AspNetCore\M\11192020_2`

I'm using the asp.net Identity for logging in. The login comes up properly and I can sign in to my web app without any issues. All the CSS and JS files are load as under the environment beta tag.

When I log in and go to the landing page, none of the JS or CSS files are loaded at all!

I'm not sure what is going on and I can't figure it out. If I publish via VS2019 and not with dotnet command line it does not work either.

If I run locally it works without any issues.

What could be the issue?

I'm using:

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "3.1.302"
  }
}
```

This project has been on hold for a couple of months so I got a new computer and wanted to make sure I could publish and run it on localhost, but I can't get past this issue!

It appears all of my minification appears to be working properly.

[image]

Here is a screen capture of my login page that is working and loading all CSS/JS fine:

[image]

Here is the page once I log in successfully with no CSS/JS injected?

[image]

Here are my console errors:

[image]

wwwroot appears to be working fine?

[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you mean that the JS and CSS files are in expected folder under wwwroot, but it can not access (404 error) from server?

Comment: @FeiHan: Yes, the files are in wwwroot as they should be, but for some reason, my MainStructure page does not have the JavaScript / CSS applied at all! I do not see them in the Element tab of F12. It is on the Login page though.

Answer (score 1):

I did not have my laptop [ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/asp-net-core/aspnetcore_environment-variable-in-asp-net-core/#windows-os) set to Beta.

Once I did that I updated this dotnet command:

`dotnet publish -r win-x64 --self-contained true -c Release -o C:\aPublish\AspNetCore\M\11192020_2`

Thanks to my Brazilian friend for the help!